# delete where you have multiple users within Dept using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to keep one user where there are multiple users for each location.  I also want to keep the user that was last updated.
here is my data

```
ID  Location   REGION    LastUpdate
1     CLT       NA       1/15/2014    
3     CLT       NA        7/02/2015   
8     NY        NA        03/03/2000
11    NY        NA        04/8/2015
```

DESIRED RESULTS

```
ID  Location   REGION    LastUpdate  
3     CLT       NA        7/02/2015   
11    NY        NA        04/8/2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC) 
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

If you want to delete the other rows, then you should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC) 
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Comment: so how do you delete it?

Comment: @moe Sorry, didn't realize you wanted to delete the other rows. Updated my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY LOCATION, Region` and then delete all the other rows that donot have the `MAX lastupdate` in that set.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT MIN(ID), LOCATION, REGION, MAX(lastUpdate)
    FROM YOURTABLE 
    GROUP BY LOCATION, REGION)
    DELETE FROM YOURTABLE
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE A.ID=CTE.ID)
```